# Google play billing for python

Tags: python, android, kivy, google-play

I'm making an android app and trying to intergrate Google play billing but I'm struggling to find a python package I can use. I'm build the app with kivy but also don't see much info on adding google play billing with kivy.

So just wondering how other people are doing it in python and/or if someone knows of a python package to use ?

Would be nice if google had a python package for it but I don't see that either. Unfortunately I'm not smart enough to work out how to merge Java into python easily.... yet :)